# Implementing HTML5 Storage API

Tags: javascript, api, local-storage

I've started a quick exercise on using local storage/session storage in JS and there seems to be an issue with my LoadFromStorage function. Every time it is called the console logs "replaceNode" is not a function.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('btnAdd').onclick = function() {
    localStorage.setItem(document.getElementById("toStorageKey").value,
      document.getElementById("toStorageValue").value);
    LoadFromStorage();
  }

  document.getElementById('btnRemove').onclick = function() {
    localStorage.removeItem(document.getElementById('toStorageKey').value);
    LoadFromStorage();
  }
  document.getElementById('btnClear').onclick = function() {
    localStorage.clear();
    LoadFromStorage();
  }

  function LoadFromStorage() {
    var storageDiv = document.getElementById('storage');
    var tbl = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.id = "storageTable";
    if (localStorage.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        var key = document.createElement("td");
        var val = document.createElement('td');
        key.innerText = localStorage.key(i);
        val.innerText = localStorage.getItem(key.innerText);
        row.appendChild(key);
        row.appendChild(val);
        tbl.appendChild(row);
      }
    } else {
      var row = document.createElement('tr');
      var col = document.createElement('td');
      col.innerText = 'No data in local storage.';
      row.appendChild(col);
      tbl.appendChild(row);
    }
    if (document.getElementById('storageTable')) {
      document.getElementById('storageTable').replaceNode(tbl);
    } else {
      storageDiv.appendChild(tbl);
    };
  };
}
```

```css
section {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  Key: <input type="text" id="toStorageKey"><br> Value: <input type="text" id="toStorageValue"><br>
</section>
<section>
  <button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add to storage</button>
  <button type="button" id="btnRemove">Remove from storage</button>
  <button type="button" id="btnClear">Clear storage</button>
</section>
<div id="storage">
  <p>Current Storage Contents</p>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no native method `replaceNode`. You probably meant https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild …?

Comment: @cfynes , I have updated the answer. you can it.

Comment: Consider using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `onclick`.

Comment: Thanks so much - I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be it not great solution but now you can able add key value in local storage.

Hope, it will help you some extend.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head> 
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <style>
            section {
                margin-top: 15px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                    document.getElementById('btnAdd').onclick = function () {
                    localStorage.setItem(document.getElementById("toStorageKey").value,
                    document.getElementById("toStorageValue").value);
                        LoadFromStorage();
                }
                   
                document.getElementById('btnRemove').onclick = function () {
                    localStorage.removeItem(document.getElementById('toStorageKey').value);
                    console.log("Remove Item",document.getElementById('toStorageKey').value)
                    LoadFromStorage();
                }
                document.getElementById('btnClear').onclick = function () {
                    localStorage.clear();
                    LoadFromStorage();
                }
                function LoadFromStorage() {
                        var storageDiv = document.getElementById('storage');
                        var tbl = document.createElement('table');
                        tbl.id = "storageTable";
                        if (localStorage.length > 0) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                                var row = document.createElement("tr");
                                var key = document.createElement("td");
                                var val = document.createElement('td');
                                key.innerText = localStorage.key(i);
                                val.innerText = localStorage.getItem(key.innerText);
                                row.appendChild(key);
                                row.appendChild(val);
                                tbl.appendChild(row);
                                }
                        } else {
                            var row = document.createElement('tr');
                            var col = document.createElement('td');
                            col.innerText = 'No data in local storage.';
                            row.appendChild(col);
                            tbl.appendChild(row);
                        }
                        if (document.getElementById('storageTable')) {
                            document.getElementById('storageTable').replaceWith(tbl);
                        } else {
                            storageDiv.appendChild(tbl);
                        };
                    };
            }
             
            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            Key: <input type="text" id="toStorageKey"><br>
            Value: <input type="text" id="toStorageValue"><br>
        </section>
        <section>
            <button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add to storage</button>
            <button type="button" id="btnRemove">Remove from storage</button>
            <button type="button" id="btnClear">Clear storage</button>
        </section>
        <div id="storage">
            <p>Current Storage Contents</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now you can able to added key and value to local Storage.

OutPut Screen-Shoot:

[image]

Comment: if it has solved your issue then Could please, accept & upvote the answer so it will help to other people. @cfynes